# MVC3 View do not show content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have problem that in my MVC 3 project, the logon view do not show although i inspected my html file and there are html elements but they do not show. Please have a look, and give me some suggestion to solve this.

Here is my view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>LogOn</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Admin/css/reset.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Admin/css/CMSS.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Admin/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Admin/scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="error-container"></div>
<div id="login-wrapper">
    <div class="background">
    <h3>
        <span class="title">CMS</span></h3>
    <div class="form">
        <p class="seperation"></p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <table>
                <col class="col-title" />
                <col class="col-value" />
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="login-title">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--<tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxRemember" runat="server" Text="Ghi nhớ" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>-->
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>

        @if (Model.EnablePasswordReset)
        {
             <p class="forgot-links">
            <a id="forgot-pass">@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password?", "ForgotPassword")</a></p>
        }
    </div>
    <p class="shadow">
    </p>
    <p class="copyright">
        <span class="copy">© 2011 CMS. All Rights Reserved.</span>
    </p>

    @{Html.RenderAction("ForgotPassword", "Account");}

</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            var viewModel = new LogOnViewModel();
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MembershipUser user = membershipService.GetUser(model.UserName);
                var role = roleService.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);
                if (authenticationService.LogOn(model.UserName, model.Password, false)) // in CMS do not for remember user for security
                {
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (IsAdministrator(role))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Admin" });
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "This account does not exist. Please try again.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!user.IsApproved)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your account has not been approved yet.");
                        }
                        else if (user.IsLockedOut)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your account is currently locked.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn");
        }
```

and the result i got from Firefox :

[image]

Comment: If you see in Firebug... the content of the body is hidden/not visible (is lighter that the rest). Do you have some CSS placed or some jQuery that could be hiding that content?

Comment: try removing all the id and classes from the elements of login page just to see if there some sort of JS or CSS rules hiding the page section

Comment: Please check the Net panel in firebug to spot out the error. And please display the screenshot of it.

Comment: @NevenHuynh, do you see anything when you press Ctrl+A (or select all) in the browser?

Comment: thanks all for your comment, these comments are very useful and help me a lot. This issue because my elements are display none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, i found out the issue. It Caused by my elements are set display none. I did not check carefully.Thanks again !